# How can I update .RData?

Tags: r, workflow, rdata

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822532/how-can-i-neatly-clean-my-r-workspace-while-preserving-certain-objects) I attempted to clean out my workspace and found that each time I opened R all the original items I had recently removed were restored.  I then checked .RData and found that it had not been modified in a few weeks even though I repeatedly saved the workspace image.  How often is .RData updated and how can I change when .RData is updated so that it reflects more recent changes?

Comment: Most of the time, you'll be better off saving your code rather than saving the objects.  Your analyses will be more transparent this way (since it isn't always obvious how a variable came to exist, and it may not mean what you think it means, six months down the line.)  The only exception is when a variable is the result of an analysis that took a long time to run, so it isn't practical to repeatedly execute your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It gets modified if and when you

1. use `save.image()`
2. use `q()` and answer yes

Otherwise it does not get changed.

My personal preference is to explicitly load and save data I want to cache across sessions or for further analysis.