# What ways are there for cleaning an R environment from objects?

Tags: r

I know I can use ls() and rm() to see and remove objects that exist in my environment.

However, when dealing with "old" .RData file, one needs to sometimes pick an environment a part to find what to keep and what to leave out.

What I would like to do, is to have a GUI like interface to allow me to see the objects, sort them (for example, by there size), and remove the ones I don't need (for example, by a check-box interface).  Since I imagine such a system is not currently implemented in R, what ways do exist?  What do you use for cleaning old .RData files?

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: Check out this related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822532/how-can-i-neatly-clean-my-r-workspace-while-preserving-certain-objects

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out the [RGtk2](http://www.ggobi.org/rgtk2/) package.
You can very easily create an interface with Glade Interface Designer and then attach whatever R commands you want to it.

If you want a good starting point where to "steal" ideas on how to use `RGtk2`, install the `rattle` package and run `rattle();`. Then look at the source code and start making your own interface :)

I may have a go at it and see if I can come out with something simple.

EDIT: this is a quick and dirty piece of code that you can play with. The big problem with it is that for whatever reason the `rm` instruction does not get executed, but I'm not sure why... I know that it is the central instruction, but at least the interface works! :D

TODO:

- Make `rm` work
- I put all the variables in the `remObjEnv` environment. It should not be listed in the current variable and it should be removed when the window is closed
- The list will only show objects in the global environment, anything inside other environment won't be shown, but that's easy enough to implement
- probably there's some other bug I haven't thought of :D

Enjoy

```
# Our environment
remObjEnv <<- new.env()

# Various required libraries
require("RGtk2")

remObjEnv$createModel <- function()
    {
    # create the array of data and fill it in
    remObjEnv$objList <- NULL
    objs <- objects(globalenv())

    for (o in objs)
        remObjEnv$objList[[length(remObjEnv$objList)+1]] <- list(object = o, 
            type = typeof(get(o)),
            size = object.size(get(o)))

    # create list store
    model <- gtkListStoreNew("gchararray", "gchararray", "gint")

    # add items 
    for (i in 1:length(remObjEnv$objList))
        {
        iter <- model$append()$iter

        model$set(iter,
              0, remObjEnv$objList[[i]]$object,
              1, remObjEnv$objList[[i]]$type,
              2, remObjEnv$objList[[i]]$size)
        }

    return(model)
    }

remObjEnv$addColumns <- function(treeview)
    {
    colNames <- c("Name", "Type", "Size (bytes)")

    model <- treeview$getModel()

    for (n in 1:length(colNames))
        {
        renderer <- gtkCellRendererTextNew()
        renderer$setData("column", n-1)
        treeview$insertColumnWithAttributes(-1, colNames[n], renderer, text=n-1)
        }
    }

# Builds the list. 
# I seem to have some problems in correctly build treeviews from glade files
# so we'll just do it by hand :)
remObjEnv$buildTreeView <- function()
    {   
    # create model
    model <- remObjEnv$createModel()
    # create tree view
    remObjEnv$treeview <- gtkTreeViewNewWithModel(model)

    remObjEnv$treeview$setRulesHint(TRUE)
    remObjEnv$treeview$getSelection()$setMode("single")

    remObjEnv$addColumns(remObjEnv$treeview)
    remObjEnv$vbox$packStart(remObjEnv$treeview, TRUE, TRUE, 0)
    }

remObjEnv$delObj <- function(widget, treeview)
    {
    model <- treeview$getModel()
    selection <- treeview$getSelection()
    selected <- selection$getSelected()
    if (selected[[1]])
        {
        iter <- selected$iter
        path <- model$getPath(iter)
            i <- path$getIndices()[[1]]
            model$remove(iter)
        }

    obj <- as.character(remObjEnv$objList[[i+1]]$object)
    rm(obj)
    }

# The list of the current objects
remObjEnv$objList <- NULL

# Create the GUI.
remObjEnv$window <- gtkWindowNew("toplevel", show = FALSE)
gtkWindowSetTitle(remObjEnv$window, "R Object Remover")
gtkWindowSetDefaultSize(remObjEnv$window, 500, 300)
remObjEnv$vbox <- gtkVBoxNew(FALSE, 5)
remObjEnv$window$add(remObjEnv$vbox)

# Build the treeview
remObjEnv$buildTreeView()

remObjEnv$button <- gtkButtonNewWithLabel("Delete selected object")
gSignalConnect(remObjEnv$button, "clicked", remObjEnv$delObj, remObjEnv$treeview)
remObjEnv$vbox$packStart(remObjEnv$button, TRUE, TRUE, 0)

remObjEnv$window$showAll()
```

Comment: Thanks Nico.  In case you succeed and getting something ready - please let me know about it (tal.galili@gmail.com)  Thanks!

Comment: @Tal Galili: I updated my answer with a piece of code. It's all for you to play with! :)

Comment: Hi Nico - wonderful, thank you! I currently can't play with it yet since I am having issue with Gtk2, but upon fixing it I will give your code a run.  Best, Tal

Comment: Nico, what do you think about the user___ idea down the thread? of using gwidgets instead of RGtk2 ?

Comment: @Tal Galili: I never used gwidgets, I guess it is an option, I generally use RGtk2 because it nicely integrates in the Gnome environment, but it's absolutely a personal preference. You can use Tcl/Tk too if you wish

Answer (score 17):

I never create `.RData` files.  If you are practicing reproducible research (and you should be!) you should be able to source in R files to go from input data files to all outputs.

When you have operations that take a long time it makes sense to cache them. If often use a construct like:

```
 if (file.exists("cache.rdata")) { 
    load("cache.rdata")
 } else {
    # do stuff ...
    save(..., file = "cache.rdata")
 }
```

This allows you to work quickly from cached files, and when you need to recalculate from scratch you can just delete all the rdata files in your working directory.

Comment: I disagreed. Each time loads all files, merge them, prepare? I choose onetime data preparation, save to .RData and do analysis from `load`.

Comment: Hi Hadley -
In theory I would take your stance, in practice it doesn't always work.  For example, I have projects where to get to the relevant data.frame, I would need several minutes of R processing. In which case I would much rather do what Marek wrote.

Comment: Caching is completely orthogonal to this working practice.  I've added a note to make that more clear.

Answer (score 5):

Basic solution is to load your data, remove what you don't want and save as new, clean data.

---

Another way to handle this situation is to control loaded RData by loading it to own environment

```
sandbox <- new.env()
load("some_old.RData", sandbox)
```

Now you can see what is inside

```
ls(sandbox)
sapply(ls(sandbox), function(x) object.size(get(x,sandbox)))
```

Then you have several posibilities:

- write what you want to new RData: `save(A, B, file="clean.RData", envir=sandbox)`
- remove what you don't want from environment `rm(x, z, u, envir=sandbox)`
- make copy of variables you want in global workspace and remove `sandbox`

I usually do something similar to third option. Load my data, do some checks, transformation, copy final data to global workspace and remove environments.

---

You could always implement what you want. So

1. Load the data
   `vars <- load("some_old.RData")`
2. Get sizes
   `vars_size <- sapply(vars, function(x) object.size(get(x)))`
3. Order them
   `vars <- vars[order(vars_size, decreasing=TRUE)]`
   `vars_size  <- vars_size [order(vars_size, decreasing=TRUE)]`
4. Make dialog box (depends on OS, here is Windows)
   `vars_with_size <- paste(vars,vars_size)`
   `vars_to_save <- select.list(vars_with_size, multiple=TRUE)`
5. Remove what you don't want
   `rm(vars[!vars_with_size%in%vars_to_save])`

To nice form of object size I use solution based on `getAnywhere(print.object_size)`

```
pretty_size <- function(x) {
    ifelse(x >= 1024^3, paste(round(x/1024^3, 1L), "Gb"),
    ifelse(x >= 1024^2, paste(round(x/1024^2, 1L), "Mb"),
    ifelse(x >= 1024  , paste(round(x/1024, 1L), "Kb"),
                        paste(x, "bytes")
    )))
}
```

Then in 4. one can use `paste(vars, pretty_size(vars_size))`

Comment: Thanks Marek.  Your code was helpful with some interesting functions and strategies.  I do hope though that something like what Nico suggested could be devised - it seems much more easy to work with.  Thanks again, Tal.

Answer (score 2):

Once you've figured out what you want to keep, you can use the function -keep- from package gdata does what its name suggests.

```
a <- 1
b <- 2
library(gdata)
keep(a, all = TRUE, sure = TRUE)
```

See help(keep) for details on the -all- and -sure- options.

```
all: whether hidden objects (beginning with a .) should be removed, unless explicitly kept.
sure: whether to perform the removal, otherwise return names of objects that would have been removed.
```

This function is so useful that I'm surprised it isn't part of R itself.

Answer (score 1):

The OS X gui does have such a thing, it's called the Workspace Browser.  Quite handy.

I've also wished for an interface that shows the session dependency between objects, i.e. if I start from a plot() and work backwards to find all the objects that were used to create it.  This would require parsing the history.

Comment: Thanks Ken - that sounds like a great idea.  Do you have a clue how it might be done ?

Comment: You can browse the workspace under any platform using `?browseEnv`.  `ls.str` provides a console alternative.

Comment: Richie - thank you, this is very cool (I knew ls.str, but not browseEnv) !

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have checkboxes to delete with, rather you select the file(s) then click delete. However, the solution below is pretty easy to implement:

```
library(gWidgets)
options(guiToolkit="RGtk2")

## make data frame with files
out <- lapply((x <- list.files()), file.info)
out <- do.call("rbind", out)
out <- data.frame(name=x, size=as.integer(out$size), ## more attributes?
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
## set up GUI
w <- gwindow("Browse directory")
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)
tbl <- gtable(out, cont=g, multiple=TRUE)
size(tbl) <- c(400,400)
deleteThem <- gbutton("delete", cont=g)
enabled(deleteThem) <- FALSE
## add handlers
addHandlerClicked(tbl, handler=function(h,...) {
  enabled(deleteThem) <- (length(svalue(h$obj, index=TRUE)) > 0)
})

addHandlerClicked(deleteThem, handler=function(h,...) {
  inds <- svalue(tbl, index=TRUE)
  files <- tbl[inds,1]
  print(files)                          # replace with rm?
})
```

Comment: Thanks user.___, I will try this as well after my RGtk2 will start working again.  Best, Tal

Comment: Hi again, I tried your code with options(guiToolkit="tcltk"), it partially worked. I can see the table of files (I actually wanted the ls() objects, but that's fine) - But I don't see the delete button (it doesn't have enough space).  Any ideas ?

Comment: Yeah, that is some bug I haven't figured out how to iron out with the table widget. A couple quick hacks are: you can manually resize the window;  move the delete button above the gtable instance, or use a horizontal layout (skipping horizontal=FALSE in ggroup) --John

Answer (score 1):

The poor guy answer could be :

```
ls()
# spot the rank of the variables you want to remove, for example 10 to 25 
rm(list= ls()[[10:25]])
# repeat until satisfied
```

Answer (score 0):

To clean the complete environment you can try:

```
rm(list(ls())
```