# Clearing all user-defined objects in R workspace

Tags: r, workspace, rserve

I'm working with Rserve via Ruby bindings.  It's pretty trivial to establish a connection to Rserve, and I assume its a good idea to persist that connection globally to avoid the overhead of tearing it down and re-building it as needed (I'm not operating in a multi-threaded environment).

Since the objects defined will stick around, and potentially class with later operations, I want to clear them out.  I've seen:

```
myvar = 1
rm(myvar)
```

However, I would rather re-initialize everything, to avoid having to manually keep track of whats defined.  Is this possible?  Is there a significant overhead associated with it if so?

Comment: Are you looking for `rm(list=ls())`?

Comment: From `?rm` : `## remove (almost) everything in the working environment.
## You will get no warning, so don't do this unless you are really sure.
rm(list = ls())`

Comment: I think adding `rm(list=ls(all=TRUE))` will remove everything or more at least.

Comment: As far as clashes go, this question may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822532/how-can-i-neatly-clean-my-r-workspace-while-preserving-certain-objects

Comment: Yes, rm(list=ls()) looks like it will hopefully do the trick.  Thanks all

Answer (score 43, accepted):

it is a bit dangerous but:

`rm(list=ls())`

really, don't do this.

Comment: how to remove some variables?

Comment: @Cina This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822532/how-can-i-neatly-clean-my-r-workspace-while-preserving-certain-objects?lq=1

Comment: Why is it a bit dangerous? Is it just that you might accidentally delete something you didn't want to?

Comment: @user1205901 That is right. My personal rule is never write it in a script, but it is OK to use at the interactive command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a dataset let say named data_new, you can use the following comment to remove all information about data_new from your workspace:

> rm(data = data_new)